# Ember Data with large JSON name/value pairs

Tags: json, ember.js, ember-data

I have a JSON file which has 30 attribute/value pairs which is potentially going to increase in size. As part of the Ember Data, I understand that each attribute needs to be defined.

```
App.Users = DS.Model.extend({
firstName: DS.attr()
lastName: DS.attr()
jobNumber: DS.attr()
...
```

I was hoping

```
App.Users = DS.Model.extend()
```

..would work but unfortunately not.

Is there a way I can avoid having to define a large number of JSON attributes?

Comment: Don't use Ember Data, it isn't required for Ember to work.

Answer (score 1):

Just define the attributes that you need in your templates, or that you will be modifying.

In that case you need all attributes, you need to list them all in the model, the reason for that is the serializer uses this values to parse the data, like a date field, or a number.

You maybe able to get around this by creating a custom adapter that assumes everything in the json as a string attribute. but I don't recommend it. its better to be explicit on the fields your model has.

Comment: Thanks for your response. What if I need to use all the attributes on one page? For example, display all the information about a user.